# How to properly write a makefile for multiple executable with same dependecies - C

Tags: c, makefile, header

Before formulating my question, I want to point out I've searched for previous answers but could not find anything useful.

I'm working on a project for my exam. Since it should consist in several executables, with various dependencies, I wanted to write a simple makefile and understand properly its behaviour for replicating it in the future if needed.

Suppose source folder consists of these files:

```
handler.c //this is the main file
server.c //another executable
client.c //another executable
header.h //each executable depends from this
header.c
procedure.h //not each executable depends from this
procedure.c
```

I know that, in order to compile these files, I should do something like that:

```
all: handler server client

handler: handler.c header.o procedure.o
    gcc handler.c -o handler header.o procedure.o

...more...

procedure.o: header.o
    gcc procedure.c -o procedure.o header.o

...more...
```

which, I'm not sure is correct at all but it's sure very tedious and long.
My question is:

is there a **faster, concise, easy** way of creating these files given my problem?
Is that possible to have a clear explaination of how it works?

I want to point out that, until now, I used this type of makefile for single executable, without problem:

```
src = $(wildcard *.c)
obj = $(src:.c=.o)
c = gcc

start: $(obj)
    $(c) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f ./start
    rm -f *~
```

which, I suppose, takes all file from my main folder, specifies dependencies as the name of file.o and then create each .o needed file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your worry, but why use clean? it will recompile every time. Otherwise it will only compile if something in the dependencies changed. It is fine to have multiple rules relying on same header.

Comment: There is not a proper worry, is just that I want to know if there is a proper way for compiling my file by using macros or others elements that would make it easier to write the makefile. As regards clean, yeah I've discovered that makefiles have such behaviour but my professor clearly requests also a clear section, I do not know why.

Comment: You goin to get a different answer from every engineer you ask this to. Ex: I would use what you had before (which is what you apparently have *last* in this post) ,but build three obj sets from three source file lists: one used by client,  one used by server, and the one shared by both. Put the client and shared objs in the client dependency list, the server and shared objs in the server dependency list. your 'all' target is dependent on 'client' and 'server' and that's it. I'm certain* others will have differing opinions, so best of luck.

Comment: The problem is that the last makefile does not create 3 executables, whereas I want it to create those 3 executables

Comment: Did you read http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ ?

Comment: `make` is all about defining dependencies. If you're not sure draw a tree showing which files depend on which other files. Add the commands to build the latter from the former. Look for common patterns. Put your findings in the Makefile using the correct syntax. Try it. Only then optimize. I'm aware that I simplified, but that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be easier if you were reworking your specifications and separating object files from executables (compilation and linking phases). Object files depend on header files and source files but executables depend only on object files. Then if you properly use pattern rules, automatic variables and if you separate the dependencies from the recipes, you could use something like:

```
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC))
EXE := handler server client

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXE)

# object files to executables dependencies
handler: handler.o header.o procedure.o
server: server.o header.o
client: client.o header.o

# header files to object files dependencies
procedure.o: procedure.h
$(OBJ): header.h

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(EXE):
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(EXE) $(OBJ)
```

Note: of course, because they cannot be guessed from your question, check the dependencies (which executable depends on which object file and which object file depends on which header file). This example Makefile is just a hint.

Note: as suggested by [Vroomfondel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819452/vroomfondel), if your compiler supports it, you could also use it to automatically detect header files to object files dependencies. Read [this](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) to know more about this.

Comment: You were faster than me, and my "solution" looks 98% equal. :-) Good work! @KingPowa You might like to use `make`'s options `-n`, `-d`, or `-p` to debug your Makefile.

Comment: @KingPowa If it does please do not forget to accept the answer such that other visitors know that it solved your problem.